# Парсинг данных полученных ajax

Tags: ajax, парсер

Есть страница domen.ru/index.php, забираю с нее информацию с помощью file_get_contents. Далее, чтоб получить следующую нужную мне информацию, на странице index.php должен отработать скрипт, который без обновления страницы, с помощью AJAX выдает новую порцию данных.
Вопрос: как мне заставить отработать этот скрипт и забрать эти данные? Ведь адрес целевой страницы не меняется (domen.ru/index.php)

Answer (score 1):

Нужно анализировать AJAX-запросы отправляемые страницей domen.ru/index.php, и скорее всего эмулировать эти запросы на бэкэнде. Т.е. как минимум попытаться открыть страницу на которую уходят AJAX-запросы при помощи функции file_get_contents, если же AJAX-запросы отсылаются с POST-параметрами, то без curl'a не обойтись.